# not working `protected $table` In the model that extends the pivot

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-10

My versions are:

- Laravel 10.13
- PHP 8.1

I have `TeamUser` model:

```php
use App\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
    
class TeamUser extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public const USER_ID = 'user_id';
    public const TEAM_ID = 'team_id';
    
    protected $table = 'table_users';
    
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function user(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
    
    public function team(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
}
```

I also have `User` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use CrudTrait;

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(TeamUser::class);
    }
}
```

And in migration:

```php
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create(Table::TEAM_USERS, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger(TeamUser::TEAM_ID);
            $table->foreign(TeamUser::TEAM_ID)->on(Table::TEAMS)->references('id')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger(TeamUser::USER_ID);
            $table->foreign(TeamUser::USER_ID)->on(Table::USERS)->references('id')->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }
```

My factory:

```php
use App\Models\Team;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class FakeDataSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        Team::factory()
            ->for(User::factory()->create(), TeamRelation::MANAGER)
            ->has(User::factory(), TeamRelation::USERS)
            ->create();
    }
}
```

I tried creating a `Team` with the factory's method `for` and `has` for seeding in the database, but when I run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, it throws this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.team_user' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `team_user` (`user_id`, `team_id`) values (19, 4))
```

I defined `protected $table = "team_users"` in `TeamUser` model but it is still not working!

Comment: If it is possible, easiest way to solve this error is to stick with Eloquent's naming convention so pivot table should be named `team_user`, same worth for methods in `TeamUser` model - should be `users` and `teams` (plural) since those return query builder object for collections.

Comment: First of all, `User::factory()->create()` in your factory should be `User::factory()`, second, what is `TeamRelation::MANAGER` on the factory?

Comment: Your error says team_user and your code says team_users which are different, this might be leading your debuggin in the wrong direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your namespace is not same as model, you missing the line `use App\Table\TeamUser;` on your `User::class`.

It because your pivot model is not loaded success in `User::class`, so Laravel try to load the `BelongsToMany` relation from the default pivot table naming.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

use App\Table\TeamUser; // Missing this.

class Team extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use CrudTrait;

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(TeamUser::class);
    }
}
```